# Cronjob for delete StoredHttpSession items Hybris

Tags: java, database, jakarta-ee, cron, sap-commerce-cloud

I need some help with some suggestions about what I will say here. I need to make a cronjob for the sap hybris platform, that deletes StoredHttpSession items older than X seconds. I really need some suggestions, because I really don't know how to start. Thanks a lot!

This paragraph is from SAP Documentation.
(Regular HttpSessions provided by Tomcat are proactively monitored for invalidation (StandardManager.processExpires). As soon as a session is a candidate for invalidation, the session is destroyed, and a sessionDestroyed event is triggered. Such mechanism is not provided with the OOTB Spring session implementation. Consequently StoredHttpSession items have no end of life and remain in the database. You can remedy this by setting up a cronjob deleting the StoredHttpSession items where the current time - modified time > 3600 seconds.)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a groovy I just created which may help you reach your purpose :

```
import de.hybris.platform.core.model.web.StoredHttpSessionModel
import de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.search.FlexibleSearchQuery
import de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.search.SearchResult

String queryString = " SELECT {pk} FROM {StoredHttpSession}  WHERE {modifiedTime} < ?specificTime"

final Date specificTime = new Date();
final FlexibleSearchQuery query = new FlexibleSearchQuery(queryString, Collections.singletonMap("specificTime", specificTime));

final SearchResult<StoredHttpSessionModel> searchResult = flexibleSearchService.search(query);

List<StoredHttpSessionModel> assetModelList = searchResult.getResult();

for (StoredHttpSessionModel storedHttpSession : assetModelList) {
    println "storedHttpSession with id session :" +storedHttpSession.sessionId + " is removed !"
    modelService.remove(storedHttpSession);
}
```

Change `specificTime` with the correct date you want to use.

You can directly use this script in a `ScriptingJob` and assign it to a cronJob, you can follow this tutorial :
http://javainsimpleway.com/dynamic-cron-job-cron-job-scripting/

However, you can also create a classic cronjob, using the same flexible search to retrieve the items you want to purge